# ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider logs and convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions

Tags: spring, spring-security, active-directory, ldap

While trying to log using AD user and password, is there a way to see logs of what happened in a login request using ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider?

I set convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions true but I don't get any messages. When I try to login all I get is a redirect to the login failure page but I do not know what happened.

```
<beans:bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" 
            class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="domain" />
        <beans:constructor-arg value="ldap://site/"/> 
        <beans:property name="userDetailsContextMapper" ref="tdrUserDetailsContextMapper"/>
        <beans:property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true"/>   
        <beans:property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="tdrUserDetailsContextMapper" class="com.test9.security9.service.CustomUserDetailsContextMapper"/>
```

Here is my custom mapper class

```
public class CustomUserDetailsContextMapper implements UserDetailsContextMapper{

   // private static final long serialVersionUID = 3962976258168853984L;

    @Override
    public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx, String username, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authority) {
        String role="admin";
        System.out.println("TEST");
        if(username.equals("usuario"))role="admin";
        else role="user";
        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authList = getAuthorities(role);

        return new User(username, "", true, true, true, true, authList);
    }



    private List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(String role) {

        List<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<SimpleGrantedAuthority>();
        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));

        //you can also add different roles here
        //for example, the user is also an admin of the site, then you can add ROLE_ADMIN
        //so that he can view pages that are ROLE_ADMIN specific
        if (role != null && role.trim().length() > 0) {
            if (role.equals("admin")) {
                authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"));
            }
        }

        return authList;
    }



    @Override
    public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails arg0, DirContextAdapter arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }
}
```

Something is not right because I the TEST message at the beginning is not printed.

Comment: And why should that appear in the logging? That is send to the system.out not your logging...

Comment: I was talking about the convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions error Messages, for some reason they weren't showing until I created a custom ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider class.

Comment: That method is only a trigger which tells that certain codes result in exceptions. Probably `AuthenticationException`s with a message, those are handled by the `ExceptionTranslationFilter` which only logs those exceptions when debug is enabled.